# TeX Live 2023 installation stuck here

Tags: texlive, texlive-2023

I was trying to install `TeX Live 2023` on a new `Win11` laptop, and the process got stuck at installing `a2ping.windows`. I tried to switch mirrors, and I think my Internet access and CPU are fairly good.

[image: it simply stuck here]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.